# Checking Types within Types in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

Im just getting moving with TypeScript so please excuse the simplicity.

**Issue:**
I am struggling to build a type for an array of arrays, which contain a string and an object each.

**Test Object:**

```
const testObject = {
  "test": {
    bgColor: "green",
    text: "hello",
    image: `./test/slideImgTest.jpg`
  },
  "test2": {
    bgColor: "blue",
    text: "goodbye",
    image: `./test/slideImgTest.jpg`
  },
  "test3": {
    bgColor: "red",
    text: "Jack",
    image: `./test/slideImgTest.jpg`
  },
}
```

**Types:**

```
interface SlideTypes {
  bgColor: string,
  text: string,
  image: string
};
type SlideTypesArray = [string, SlideTypes][];
```

**What Im doing with that data:**

```
const allSlideData: [string, SlideTypesArray] = Object.entries(testObject);
```

**Error message:**

> Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.

**Questions:**

I understand what the error message is telling me but I thought I was supplying 2 elements with this execution.

Am I not passing multiple elements?
Are elements types?
Is it my syntax?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is that you are typing `allSlideData` incorrectly, it should be `const allSlideData: SlideTypesArray = Object.entries(testObject);` (an array of arrays instead of an array containing two elements, a string and a SlideTypesArray),

Comment: `const allSlideData: [string, SlideTypesArray] = ['Presentation', Object.entries(testObject)];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const allSlideData: [string, SlideTypesArray]` means that `allSlideData` is an array where the first element is a `string` and the second element is a `SlideTypesArray`.

But the value that you assign to `allSlideData` is `Object.entries(testObject)` which is an array of any length, depending on how many entries there are in `testObject`.  Thus you get the error *"Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer."* Target refers to the type while source refers to the value.

`Object.entries` returns an `array` where each element is an `array` with two elements: `[key, value]`.  That is the type that you described here:

```
type SlideTypesArray = [string, SlideTypes][];
```

So you want

```
const allSlideData: SlideTypesArray = Object.entries(testObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for extending @crashmstr answer, both helped me see my mistake but of course, I can't accept comments on the original post. This also gave a bit more of an understanding. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that

But that way `(Object.values)` you do not have the key of the object

```
const allSlideData: SlideTypes[] = Object.values(testObject);
```

OR this way without lost key

```
interface SlideTypesArray {
    name: string
    slide: SlideTypes
}


const allSlideData: SlideTypesArray[] = Object.entries(testObject).map(([key, value]) => ({ name: key, slide: value }))
```